# Why aiohttp "unpacks" file?

Tags: python, aiohttp

```
app.router.add_static(
    '/' + config['prefix'] + '/',
    config['path'],
    show_index=True
)
```

File on server:

```
/path/name.ext.gz 53kB
```

Downloaded with browser and with aiohttp client:

```
name.ext.gz 270k
```

If i download file named `filename.ext.gz` from aiohttp server it adds `Content-Encoding: gzip` header so file saved unpacked with `.gz` extension.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Etag: "16efd6039819648c-d1ae"
< Last-Modified: Tue, 17 May 2022 08:08:20 GMT
< Content-Length: 53678
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Tue, 17 May 2022 09:25:30 GMT
< Server: Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.8.1
```

How to fix it to not add `Content-Encoding: gzip` ?

How to add `Content-Encoding: gzip` for file compressed, but without gz extension? (for reducing storage on server)

Comment: To rephrase: you want to prevent `aiohttp` from automatically inflating gzip encoded responses?

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html?highlight=gzip#streaming-response-content…?

Comment: @deceze if i downloading archive - i need archive. Feature of serving gz wariant instead of target file breaks downloading gz variant directly.

Comment: and i cant use this feature if no file without gz

Comment: Arguably the server shouldn't serve the file as "Content-Encoding: gzip" then, since that implies the client should decode it. But anyway, the aforelinked documentation shows how to read the raw response in chunks; when using `.content` or similar, it will be implicitly decoded.